# Mad Max-inspired pop music video with paint effects, in which a female lead singer throws a grenade at marauders attacking her group

Tags: story-identification, music-video

I'm trying to get a Christmas present for a friend from an artist/band that she likes. I don't remember the name, but I do remember a music video of them that she showed me.

In the video, a group of men and women are driving across a post-apocalyptic desert wasteland in two to three cars. The costume and vehicle designs are very reminiscent of *Mad Max*. They're attacked by a group of scarier-looking survivors. One of their vehicles is destroyed and they're forced to crowd onto their remaining one. I believe paint is used to add a dramatic flair. Eventually, the lead singer, a dark-haired, fair-skinned woman, blows up the marauders with an explosive.

I believe the music style was pop and that it was fairly recent.

Comment: And merry Christmas to the both of you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be *Machine* (2017) by MisterWives.

- It's quite *Mad Max*-y save for some very colorful people;
- lead female singer fits "dark-haired, fair-skinned woman" description;
- you can see the three cars starting from 0'26;
- the baddies are spotted at 1'43 and attack at 2'07;
- grenade gets thrown at them at 3'08.

---

Found with the Google query `music videos inspired by mad max`, second page of results yielded [this ABCNewsRadio article on the video](http://abcnewsradioonline.com/music-news/2017/4/4/watch-now-misterwives-premieres-mad-max-inspired-machine-vid.html).